# I'm getting the following error while running ant script, cannot run program ant createprocess error=2 the system cannot find the file specified

Tags: ant

here i want to execute build.xml(located in the path specified), where im executing this exec task in testbuild.xml. how can i resolve this issue?

```
        <exec executable="ant" dir="${Build.WorkingCopyPath}/Build/src"
         resultproperty="${buildlogs}/@{corporateparam}_build.log">
```

-
Thanks,

Comment: The <exec> task cannot find the 'ant' executable - probably because it is not on the path. Look at using the <ant> task.

Comment: ya good, but im need of gathering log file. by using resultproperty in exec i can able to get log file. rather in ant task i cant able to store my log file.

Answer (score 1):

the following code working fine.

```
  <exec executable="cmd" dir="${Build.WorkingCopyPath}/Build/src">
    <arg value="/c" />
    <arg value="ant.bat" />
  </exec>
```